# How to make txt file opened up after data have been written to it?

Tags: java, file, file-io, file-handling, fileinputstream

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class OutputToFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Flight> flightList = new ArrayList<Flight>();
        try {
            BufferedReader filein = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("flight.dat")));
            PrintWriter fileout = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
            String line;
            String from = null;
            String to = null;
            String flightNo = null;
            String date = null;
            String departure = null;

            if (filein != null) { // not null if file exist
                while ((line = filein.readLine()) != null) { //has more line to read
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
                    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                         from = st.nextToken();
                         to = st.nextToken();
                         flightNo = st.nextToken();
                         date = st.nextToken();
                         departure = st.nextToken(); 
                    }
                    Flight f = new Flight(from, to, flightNo, date, departure);
                    flightList.add(f);
                }
            }

            fileout.println("Total number of flights :"+ flightList.size());
            fileout.println("== Flight Plan ==");
            for (Flight f: flightList) { 
                fileout.println();
                fileout.println("From : "+ f.getFrom());
                fileout.println("To : "+ f.getTo());
                fileout.println("Flight Number : "+ f.getFlightNum());
                fileout.println("Date : "+ f.getDate());
                fileout.println("Departure Time : "+ f.getDepartureTime());
            }
            filein.close();
            fileout.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

So, this program reads data from ***flight.dat*** and write the data into ***output.txt***. After that, I have to manually open up the "***output.txt***" file to check if data has been written or not. Is there a way to make ***output.txt*** file to be run (as it were double clicked) by the end of the java program? If there is such a way, is it possible to also run any file as desired (maybe an mp3 file)? One more thing, is there any recommendation on my code to make it better? Thank you guys for all your help. :)

Comment: Why don't you print the file content after writing (i.e. at the end)? Also do you need array list or can you write it simply when you read?

Comment: hmm I agree with what you said about ArrayList. I don't actually need it. Thank you very much, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html

In your particular case, this might do the trick:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("output.txt"));
```